# Calculating the distance between a line segment and a point

Tags: java, geometry

I am currently developing a tower defense game in java from scratch and I am reworking the bullet collisions. for this I need to calculate the distance between a given point and a line segment. I have already written a function to do just that, but it does often give the distance from one of the points when it is not supposed to.

the line segment class:

```java
public class LineSegment {
    public Vector2DK p;
    public Vector2DK q;

    /**
     * Creates a line segment between the points P and Q
     * @param p Point P
     * @param q Point Q
     */
    public LineSegment(Vector2DK p, Vector2DK q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the distance to point R
     * @param r Point R
     * @return Distance
     */
    public double distanceFrom(Vector2DK r) {
        // after trying what feels like everything I might have gotten a little confused(stupid errors ahead)
        Vector2DP differenceVector = r.subtract(p).toPolar();
        Vector2DP differenceVector2 = r.subtract(q).toPolar();
        double alpha = differenceVector.getAngle() - q.subtract(p).getAngle();
        double beta = differenceVector2.getAngle() - q.subtract(p).getAngle();
        if (alpha < Math.PI / 2 && alpha > -Math.PI / 2) {
            return p.distanceTo(r);
        } else if (beta > Math.PI / 2 || beta < -Math.PI / 2) {
            return q.distanceTo(r);
        }
        return Math.abs(differenceVector.getMagnitude() * Math.sin(alpha));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // a main method for testing 
        // I already added a case where the bullet of the tower flew right thru the enemy(but I probably got the wrong tick, so the values are probably not good for testing)
        Vector2DK linePoint0 = new Vector2DK(339.9354152826523, 374.7835775987438);
        Vector2DK linePoint1 = new Vector2DK(317.79869321314067, 388.4287303893724);

        Vector2DK point = new Vector2DK(290.0194200000002, 400.0);

        LineSegment lineSegment = new LineSegment(linePoint0, linePoint1);
        Line line = new Line(linePoint0, linePoint1);
        System.out.println(lineSegment.distanceFrom(point));
    }
}
```

my two vector classes:

```java
public class Vector2DK implements Vector2D {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Vector2DK(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Vector2DK(Vector2D vector) {
        Vector2DK vector2DK = vector.toKartesian();
        x = vector2DK.x;
        y = vector2DK.y;
    }

    public void copyToSelf(Vector2DK vector) {
        x = vector.x;
        y = vector.y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Vector2DK(%s, %s)", x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2DK toKartesian() {
        return new Vector2DK(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2DP toPolar() {
        return new Vector2DP(getMagnitude(), getAngle());
    }

    @Override
    public double getAngle() {
        return Math.atan2(y, x);
    }

    @Override
    public double getMagnitude() {
        return Math.sqrt(getMagnitudeSquare());
    }

    @Override
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAngle(double angle) {
        Vector2DP vector = toPolar();
        vector.setAngle(angle);
        copyToSelf(vector.toKartesian());
    }

    @Override
    public void setMagnitude(double magnitude) {
        Vector2DP vector = toPolar();
        vector.setAngle(magnitude);
        copyToSelf(vector.toKartesian());
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public double getMagnitudeSquare() {
        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    @Override
    public double distanceTo(Vector2D vector) {
        return Math.sqrt(MathFunc.square(x - vector.getX()) + MathFunc.square(y - vector.getY()));
    }

    @Override
    public void normalize() {
        double magnitude = getMagnitude();
        x /= magnitude;
        y /= magnitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void reverse() {
        x = -x;
        y = -y;
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2D add(Vector2D vector) {
        return new Vector2DK(x + vector.getX(), y + vector.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2D subtract(Vector2D vector) {
        return new Vector2DK(x - vector.getX(), y - vector.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2D scale(double value) {
        return new Vector2DK(x * value, y * value);
    }

    @Override
    public void addWith(Vector2D vector) {
        x += vector.getX();
        y += vector.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void subtractWith(Vector2D vector) {
        x -= vector.getX();
        y -= vector.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void scaleWith(double value) {
        x *= value;
        y *= value;
    }

    @Override
    public double dotProduct(Vector2D vector) {
        return x * vector.getX() + y * vector.getY();
    }
}
```

and:

```java
public class Vector2DP implements Vector2D {
    private double magnitude;
    private double angle;

    public Vector2DP(double magnitude, double angle) {
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public Vector2DP(Vector2DP vector) {
        Vector2DP vector2DP = vector.toPolar();
        this.magnitude = vector.magnitude;
        this.angle = vector.angle;
    }

    public void copyToSelf(Vector2DP vector) {
        magnitude = vector.magnitude;
        angle = vector.angle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Vector2DP(%su, %s°)", magnitude, Math.toDegrees(angle));
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2DK toKartesian() {
        return new Vector2DK(getX(), getY());
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2DP toPolar() {
        return new Vector2DP(magnitude, angle);
    }

    @Override
    public double getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    @Override
    public double getMagnitude() {
        return magnitude;
    }

    @Override
    public double getX() {
        return Math.cos(angle) * magnitude;
    }

    @Override
    public double getY() {
        return Math.sin(angle) * magnitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAngle(double angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMagnitude(double magnitude) {
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(double x) {
        Vector2DK vector = toKartesian();
        vector.setX(x);
        copyToSelf(vector.toPolar());
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(double y) {
        Vector2DK vector = toKartesian();
        vector.setY(y);
        copyToSelf(vector.toPolar());
    }

    @Override
    public double getMagnitudeSquare() {
        return magnitude * magnitude;
    }

    @Override
    public double distanceTo(Vector2D vector) {
        return subtract(vector).getAngle();
    }

    @Override
    public void normalize() {
        magnitude = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void reverse() {
        angle += angle < Math.PI ? Math.PI : -Math.PI;
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2D add(Vector2D vector) {
        return toKartesian().add(vector).toPolar();
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2D subtract(Vector2D vector) {
        return toKartesian().add(vector).toPolar();
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2D scale(double value) {
        return new Vector2DP(magnitude * value, angle);
    }

    @Override
    public void addWith(Vector2D vector) {
        copyToSelf((Vector2DP) add(vector));
    }

    @Override
    public void subtractWith(Vector2D vector) {
        copyToSelf((Vector2DP) subtract(vector));
    }

    @Override
    public void scaleWith(double value) {
        magnitude *= value;
    }

    @Override
    public double dotProduct(Vector2D vector) {
        Vector2DP vector2DP = vector.toPolar();
        return magnitude * vector2DP.magnitude * Math.cos(angle - vector2DP.angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! you are not telling why it does not work, what is the input and the expected output, error message and what have you tried so far.

Comment: This looks much to complicated. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: 1. I do not know why it does not work
2. i was not able to get proper data on expected i/o but the closest I could get is in the main method in LineSegment
3. i do not have an error message because it does not throw an error
4. I tried multiple times to come up with a solution by myself but could not find a working one. i also searched on stack overflow but the code either did not work or I was unable to translate it to java.

Comment: @Morgan Kuhles Have you tried my answer? Approach is like yours, but vector arithmetic is more error-prone than angle calculations.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the next Python code (hope it is easy to translate it).

At first function check dot products of segment vector and vectors from the start and end of segment to the point.

If projection of point onto the line lies outside the segment, sign of dot product reveals this fact, and we return distance to the closest segment end (points A,B,C,D at the picture)

Otherwise we return length of projection ([formula from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points)) (point E at the picture)

[image]

`hypot` gives vector length (like your `getMagnitude`)

```
import math

def pt_seg_dist(px, py, qx, qy, rx, ry):
    qpx = qx - px
    qpy = qy - py
    rpx = rx - px
    rpy = ry - py
    if rpx * qpx + rpy * qpy <= 0:
        return math.hypot(rpx, rpy)
    rqx = rx - qx
    rqy = ry - qy
    if rqx * qpx + rqy * qpy >= 0:
        return math.hypot(rqx, rqy)
    return abs(rpx * qpy - rpy * qpx) / math.hypot(qpx, qpy)

print(pt_seg_dist(0, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 2))
print(pt_seg_dist(0, 0, 1, 0, -2, 2))
print(pt_seg_dist(0, 0, 1, 0, 3, -2))

>>>
2.0
2.8284271247461903
2.8284271247461903
```